# unzip file using 7z in powershell

Tags: powershell, 7zip

What is the command to unzip a file using 7z in powershell?

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
sz x  $zipfilePath $destinationUnzipPath -aoa -r;
```

The command works fine but it says **no files to process, everything is Ok** rather than unzipping the file?

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight: **The only problem turned out to be the syntax of the `7z.exe` command - the fact that `7z` was invoked from _PowerShell_ (via an alias) was _incidental_.**

Comment: Thanks I wanted to test a zip file. Your answer got me started.
line1:sz t $zipfile
line 2 echo $LASTEXITCODE  #0 for success else http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/exit_codes.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This finally worked for me `sz x -o$destinationUnzipPath $zipfilePath -r ;`

Answer (score 10):

I didn't want to use aliases, functions or `Start-Process`. After a little looking around the web, I've found this gem (and I can't remember where):

```
& ${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe x $zipfilePath "-o$($destinationUnzipPath)" -y
```

And you can add a `> $null` at the end if you don't want to see 7z's messages!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me work around this known bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/69

Comment: Thanks, this work on powershell terminal; but cannot run on YML script file.

Answer (score 8):

With 7zip PowerShell module, now it is hassle free

```
#   Install 7zip module

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name 7Zip4PowerShell -Force

#   Extract 7zip file

$sourcefile = "c:\source\sample.7z"
Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName $sourcefile -TargetPath 'c:\destinaation'
```

Comment: If someone needs a code that works like clockwork on windows 7, windows 8 & 8.1, windows 10, this is the right one to use ;) The .Net version from microsoft is unreliable on some older windows OS. By the way this is what chocolatey package manager  (chocolatey.org) use !

Answer (score 2):

This command works well. It extracts the zip file to the destination directory:

```
$DESTINATION_DIR="C:\my_destination"
& "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe" x $ZIP_FILE "-o$($DESTINATION_DIR)" -aoa -r
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

My use case was slightly different because I had multiple tar files in a directory that needed to be extracted. I'm sharing it because same command may also be used or slighly modified to be used:

here is the command that worked for me on Windows 10 via Powershell:

Notice: you need to change the paths below for your use case of course.

```
$srcFolderPathWithTar="C:\SomeFilder\has\multiple\tar\files"
$targ="C:\Users\your_user_name\Downloads\new" 

. "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"  x "-o$($targ)" "$srcFolderPathWithTar" -r -y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `"fullname"`, which includes the path.
Also, I had to change my directory in PowerShell to the output directory of the extracted data, i.e. `D:\temp`

I refuse to believe that copying or extracting a bunch of files from disparate folders to a single location is a complicated task in this age.

```
$rars = (Get-ChildItem "D:\Path\To\folder" -Recurse *.rar).fullname
foreach ($rar in $rars) {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e $rar}
```