# Powershell - unzip 7z file

Tags: powershell

I've got a problem with unzipping 7z file with Powershell although much needed information is here:
[unzip file using 7z in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998669/unzip-file-using-7z-in-powershell)

When i use same approach:

```
$7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
Set-Alias 7zip $7zipPath
$ZipFilePath = "C:\Users\lpiech\Documents\Lukasz\PowerShell\Test\20200113.7z"
$DestinationUzipPath = "C:\Users\lpiech\Documents\Lukasz\PowerShell\Test\"
7zip x -o$DestinationUzipPath $ZipFilePath -r;
```

i get this answer [ResultsScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Mw2.png)
but in destination i don't have any files in "Test" folder and script isn't finished it stops i "Running" mode. What should i do to get unzipped files?

Comment: Ok, i have answer. Maybe someone could use it. I've changes last line of code like this: 


     '7zip x -o"$DestinationUzipPath" $ZipFilePath -r;'

Answer (score 0):

Why do people like doing it the hard way?

```
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files\7-Zip'
7zip x -oDocuments\Lukasz\PowerShell\Test Documents\Lukasz\PowerShell\Test\20200113.7z -r
```

Comment: Doesn't work: 7zip : The term '7zip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,

Comment: @DennisKassel I'm assuming 7zip is installed in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with PowerShell 7zip module, it is hassle free

```
#   Install 7zip module

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name 7Zip4PowerShell -Force

#   Extract 7zip file

$sourcefile = "c:\source\sample.7z"
Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName $sourcefile -TargetPath 'c:\destinaation'
```