# using windows batch script to automate unzip task

Tags: batch-file, automation, 7zip

I have two issues with this code I have attached below,

1. **it doesn't delete the original file** after unzip, I want the script to delete the original file from source folder
2. the converted file is not saved in **target** folder as set but it creates a tree of the directory in the same folder of the script and saved output there.

**Please help me solve this issue**

**Sample code I have tried**

```
@echo off
set "source=%userprofile%\Desktop\basanta\Automation\a"
set "target=%userprofile%\Desktop\basanta\Automation\b"
FOR %%A IN ("%source%\*.gz") DO (
     "%programfiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~A" -o"%target%\%%~pA"
     del "%%~A" /Y
)
```

Please help me to write the script as described above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998669/unzip-file-using-7z-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

try: del file /f /q
try to enclose -o parameter with a quotes: "-o%target%"